# SQL Query Issue: Not Taking Into Effect a Portion of the Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

My problem is this:  I have a MS SQL query that is combining games played and games scores for different users and using aggregate functions in a two part calculation to get a combined score.  For some reason, one part of the calculation (the first part of the calculation - games played) is not being used in the total score (I call it Algoscore).  The query is below:

```
SELECT TOP 10
  COUNT(TourScore.TourScoreID) AS GameCount,
  AVG(GameScore.GameScore) AS AVGScore,
  Users.UserID, Users.DisplayName,
  (((COUNT(TourScore.TourScoreID) / 750) * .50) * 100)
    + (((AVG(GameScore.GameScore) / 14695) * .50) * 100) AS Algoscore
FROM TourScore INNER JOIN GameScore
    ON TourScore.GameScoreID = GameScore.GameScoreID
  INNER JOIN Users
    ON GameScore.UserID = Users.UserID
WHERE (GameScore.ScoreDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '06/01/2013') 
GROUP BY Users.UserID, Users.DisplayName
ORDER BY Algoscore DESC
```

The calculation part of the SELECT:
`(((COUNT(TourScore.TourScoreID) / 750) * .50) * 100) + (((AVG(GameScore.GameScore) / 14695) * .50) * 100) AS Algoscore`
is basically ignoring the first part of the calculation: `(((COUNT(TourScore.TourScoreID) / 750) * .50) * 100)`

The second part is calculating fine so when I run the query, the `Algoscore` is only the second part of the equation, not the first and second part of the equation combined as it should be.

I hope this makes sense.  Any advice on this?  Can I even execute a query like this using an equation with aggregate functions to get another value?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is ignoring the first part? Do you mean it is returning 0?

Comment: Are either `TourScore.TourScoreID` or `GameScore.GameScore` nullable fields?

Comment: It's just not using the first part in calculating the Algoscore.  Baseically, it's only using the second part of the equation: (((AVG(GameScore.GameScore) / 14695) * .50) * 100) to calcuate the Algoscore and not using the first part at all (it's ignoring it completely): (((COUNT(TourScore.TourScoreID) / 750) * .50) * 100).

Comment: @tommy_o - No, they are not nullable fields.

Comment: Need to seed a float on division, ie:  change 750 to 750.0   
Edit: beaten to the punch.

Comment: @Goat_CO Technically, it would be a decimal, not a float.

Comment: This isn't part of your question, but you should [avoid the use of BETWEEN](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (especially for date/time types, but for _all_ 'imprecise' ranges).  In addition, the date/time format you've shown is ambiguous - [it's better to use 'YYYYMMDD' instead](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries), at least in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COUNT(ColumnName)` always returns an integer.  When you divide an integer by another integer, the result is always an integer.

For example, if you run this in a query window:

```
Select 5 / 10
```

You probably expect 0.5 as the result.  Instead, you get 0 because of integer math.  I would suggest that you make one small change to your code.

Change this:

```
COUNT(TourScore.TourScoreID) / 750
```

To this:

```
COUNT(TourScore.TourScoreID) / 750.0
```

Comment: That fixed it!!  Wow, it's amazing how something so minor can cause such massive problems.  Thanks a mil!!!